# mysql query column that contain text

Tags: mysql

The mysql table that I'm using looks like:

```
   id    |   name  | other_names  
 ---------------------------------
    1    |  john   | peter johny mike
    2    |  jane   | kevin pite janes john
    3    |  carl   | carlo nick pole
```

I want to get as a result of the query id# of each user that in the table "other_names" contains  the names starting with the word from the query. For example, if the word in query is "joh" a need to get as result ID 1 and 2.

I tried with a query containing LIKE %joh%  but as a result I'm getting each user ID# that the column "other names" has a name that contains the word from the query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE  '".$word."%' OR other_names LIKE '%".$word."%'
```

I need that the names from column "other_names" begins with the word from the query, not to contains the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) operator and border keyword

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP '[:<:]]someword'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading `%` from your query

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE other_names LIKE '".$word."%'
```